# Understanding time dilation in layman's terms

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, time-dilation

I would love to have a better understanding of Einstein's theory of relativity and how time dilation in particular works with a simple example.

Let's say I have twins. One takes a trip to a far away galaxy 10 light years away with some amazing technology traveling at .9999 the speed of light. Not calculating the exact math but this journey would take a bit over 10 years.

My understanding is that back on Earth, time would have elapsed far more than 10 years. At this point our twin back on Earth might have had multiple generations pass by now.

Our other twin now returns home, is it correct to say that our traveling twin could meet his great great great great etc nephews and nieces?

If I understand the outcome correctly, why does that happen?
I keep wanting to equate it to time zone changes on an airplane where on the return trip, the time change is reversed. How should I change my way of thinking about spacetime?

Comment: Your example is incorrect. The time elapsed on Earth would only be slightly more than ten years, while the traveling twin would experience a much smaller time. To meet his future relatives, he would have to make a much longer trip.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a mountain trip.

Suppose that two twins living in a wide mountain range such as the Himalayas want to hike from a town in a valley to another town, several valleys away.

One of the twin, which is in great shape and loves high summits, takes a short path across the mountains. The other one prefers a less intensive hike and follows a long way along the rivers at the bottom of the valleys, maybe crossing a few mountain passes.

The twins eventually both reach the same town, and eventually meet there. They do not reach the town having travelled the same distance, and not at the same time, but when they meet it is in the same place and at the same time.

No wonder here - there is nothing strange in this story, ok? There is nothing surprising in the fact that there are different ways to go from a place to another one, and that depending on the way you choose it takes more or less travelled distance to do so.

Let's call spacetime event A when and where the twins parted to start their trip. Spacetime event B is when and where they meet again. In our classical intuition, and in reality with a great precision, both twins in B have the same age, because they spent the same time during their whole separation, although one of them had to wait for the other to arrive.

I insist on the point that we do not find anything surprising in the fact that it took different travelled distances for the twins to "move" from event A to event B. I wrote "move" because the time spent by one twin to wait for the other to arrive is also taken into account, although that twin does not physically move, only waits. In that regard it is also obvious to us that it took them the same time duration.

But this last point is wrong. It took them a very similar duration, so much that it is nearly impossible to measure the difference, but not exactly the same.

Relativity tells us that it takes them exactly the same spacetime interval to "move" from A to B. Not approximately - exactly. This interval is the four-dimensional distance between A and B in spacetime.

In our example, the A-B interval is decomposed in different ways by each of the twins during their separation, because they follow different worldlines. One of them experienced a long distance, and the other a shorter one. They experienced almost the same duration, with a very tiny difference that in fact compensates for the different distances.

Our intuition finds this kind of decomposition normal and usual, and so has always completely discarded the time part. In relativity, which takes into account all possible decompositions of the spacetime interval, it is not surprising that "moving" from A to B may take both different distances and different durations, depending on the followed path (a worldline).

Answer (score 0):

First postulate SR: Locally all systems of reference are equivalent. So 0.9999 c with respect to system 1 means -0.9999 c with respct to system 2. Sending their standard comoving time ticks by light both receive their respective signal time intervals extremely red shifted. As long a they travel away from each other as relative speed 0.9999 (because c+c=c when doing addition of relative speeds). If one twin reverses speed to -0.99999, the same number of ticks arrives blue shifted in a second. So for the twin at rest the travel time on his clock at rest is mapped t two intervals, the redshifted signals of departure and the same number of ticks on a neglegible time interval for return.

So in these extreme experiments the recorded proper time over the jouney is twice the Doppler redshifted number of ticks, meaning that the time length of the journey goes to zero as v->c.

GR is nothing more than elevating the proper time on paths in a space-time manifold to the fundamental metric length locally, its total time defining the metric lenghth of paths.

Bottom line: The force free motion in space-time between two event-points is rest in a system where both space points are identical, or, mathematically, the solution of the geodetic equations of motion the least expensive of longest time travel.

Its a bit paradoxial, that any deviation from the shortest path in space for a travel betwenn two points in space in a given coordinate time interval saves proper travel time in SR.

Answer (score 0):

Your time zone idea is not far off, but you have to adjust it in two ways.

Firstly, within a time zone there is constant time, so you only seem to lose an hour (ie be time dilated by an hour) once you reach a new zone heading east. In SR the time dilation effect is gradual, rather than being in hour steps, so imagine if the time zones where replaced by a gradually increasing time as you headed east.

The second difference is that on Earth time zones are dependent on direction- time advances going east, retards going west, and doesn't vary when you head due north or south. In SR the gradual increase in time is in whichever direction you are moving.

So imagine that effect on Earth, where you travel east on a road lined with clocks and every mile takes you into an area where the clocks are another few seconds ahead of your watch. Your watch would seem to be losing time, ie to be running slow, or time dilated. It isn't running slow at all- it is ticking at the same rate as the clocks you pass- it only seems to be running slow because the clocks you pass are all gradually set further ahead in time.

That's how time dilation works. It happens because there is no fixed direction of time in spacetime, rather as there is no fixed direction of left and right in space, since it depends on where you are facing. If you and I are stationary relative to each other, we have a common direction of time, but once we start to move relative to each other, your time axis tilts relative to mine, and vice versa. The tilt means that a plane of constant time in your frame becomes a sloping slice through time in my frame, the slope being upwards in your direction of travel, while a plane of constant time in my frame becomes a sloping slice through time in yours, again with the slope being upwards in my direction of travel. To me, each of the clocks I pass in your frame is set slightly ahead of the last one I passed, and you think the same about the clocks in my frame. My watch seems to be losing time compared to the clocks I pass in your frame, and your watch seems to be losing time compared to the clocks you pass in mine. All the clocks and watches are ticking at the same rate, but the tilting time axes means that our watches are falling behind the clocks we pass and thus appear to be running slow.

Because time in another frame always slopes upwards in the direction you are moving, if you reverse your direction, what used to be a downward slope behind you, now becomes an upward slope ahead of you. This is effectively what causes the twin paradox. Suppose it is 2025 on your watch and you are heading away from Earth at some great distance. Because of the sloping time effect we discussed above, 'now' in your time frame is a sloping slice in Earth time, with the slope going up in your direction of travel away from Earth and down in the opposite direction. Earth is a long way down a slope through time behind you. Let's say it is five years down the slope, so that your 'now' is actually 2020 on Earth.  If you suddenly reverse direction, your time axis tilts in the opposite direction, and now, instead of Earth being five years lower on a downward slope through time behind you, it is now five years higher on an upward slope in front of you. Your 'now' has become 2030 on Earth, so it has skipped ten years.